# Node js - Push() Function Not working Correctly with reference and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, push

I am using ObjectReferences and push the comment data to the database but it's not working Even the data is being saved but only 'id' get added, not the user and comment

**Main File with Push Method**

```
var Comment = require('./models/comments'),
    Camp = require('./models/user');    
app.post('/camp/:id/comment', (req,res)=>{
Camp.findById(req.params.id, (err, idf)=>{
    if(err){
    console.log(err);
    }else{

    Comment.create(req.body.comment, (err, commentz)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log(commentz + idf);
      idf.comments.push(commentz)
      idf.save();
      res.redirect('/camp/'+ idf._id)
    }
    })
    }
})
})
```

**ObjectReferences user.js**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var blogSchema = new schema({
name : String,
email  : String,
descr : String,  // TEMPORERY
posts: [
{
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'Post'

}
],
comments: [
    {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment'
    }
]
});

var Camp = mongoose.model("Camp", blogSchema);
module.exports= Camp;
```

**CommentSchema comments.js**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var cSchema = new schema({
user : String,
comment  : String,
})

var Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", cSchema);
module.exports =Comment;
```

**Main Form**

```
    <form action="/camp/<%=camp._id%>/comment" method="post" class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment[user]" value="" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" style="height:100px" type="text" name="comment[comment]" value="" placeholder="Your Comment"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" type="submit" name="submit"> SUBMIT</button>
</div>
</form>
```

The only ID added to the user's database, not all comments and in the comment, collection data added perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of using `commentz` use `commentz._id` and have a callback for `.save`. It should work.

```
  console.log(commentz + idf);
  idf.comments.push(commentz._id)
  idf.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      // handle error
    }
    res.redirect('/camp/'+ idf._id)
  });
```

Comment: yes now whenever you're retrieving it you'll have to populate it like this. `Camp.findById({}).populate('comments').exec(function(err, camps){ // it will get you the whole data })`

Comment: never store same data twice. Always store the reference

Comment: Thanks, brother, its working fine ...  I use my code from udemy course 'the web developer bootcamp' and they use the same code and it works for them but not working for me .. if it does not work then how does it work for them ???

Comment: Hi , I'll have to check there code can't say what they did.